# Onchange Event my filter value get empty in List?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I'm updated my original array to become reactive template for my students array list with selection of name in JS ? when i select the button  first time it brings up the filter correct value but if click on second iterative button it shows []. what's wrong with my code ?

```
 handlechange(event)
    
        {
         const value = event.target.value;
        this.students = this.students.filter(e=>e.name.startsWith(value));
        
        }

  

    <table className="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  
                    <th>ID</th>  
                    <th>Name</th>  
                    <th>Email</th>  
                </tr>  
        
                {students.map((student, index) => (  
                  <tr data-index={index}>  
                    <td>{student.id}</td>  
                    <td>{student.name}</td>  
                    <td>{student.email}</td>  
                  </tr>  
                ))}  
               <button onclick={this.handlechange(student.name)}>click </button>
            </table>
```

Comment: The `this.students.filter()` function returns a new array, which you're then assigning to `this.students`. A second call to `this.students.filter()` filters the *already filtered* array that you've stored, thus returning `[]`.

Comment: @BrendanBond please help me to correct this error.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post a [minimal, reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I'd be happy to help, but I need more context to figure out exactly how you're rendering this stuff.

Comment: I can tell you that you shouldn't modify `this.students` - when you filter it, store the resulting filtered array in a new variable and use that for display (i.e. map over it), and keep the `this.students` array complete so you can filter multiple times.

Comment: @BrendanBond render part  i can manage only help me at the JS part.  how do i keep value for second ,.. etc call too ? please help me which es6 function i could use to keep my all filter value update based on the target value ?

Answer (score 1):

Use another array to store (and display) your results.  Do not modify your source.

```js
handlechange(event)
{
  const value = event.target.value;
  this.filteredStudents = this.students.filter(e=>e.name.startsWith(value));       
}
```

Comment: THanks for your response .but how do i keep it reactive with my html if i introduce one new array in my Handlechange(event) ?

Comment: my original array is students array how do i mutate without original array with filtered value

Comment: Create a second reactive value, right next to your students declaration.